# Is there a typo this theorem in Munkres's Topology? If not please explain

Tags: general-topology

> [image]

Doesn't he mean that the first inequality shows that $B_\rho \subset B_d$ instead? Since the distance $d(x,y)$ is larger than $\rho(x,y)$. The same goes for the second inequality.

Comment: Imagine that $\rho$ measures distance in miles and $d$ measures distance in kilometers. The distance in miles is a smaller number than the distance in kilometers, so points within $\epsilon$ kilometers of $x$ are always within $\epsilon$ miles of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y\in B_d$, then $d(x,y)<\varepsilon $. But then $\rho (x,y)\le d(x,y)<\varepsilon $ showing that $y\in B_\rho$.